# Validate angularjs model before value is set

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the an input field where only positive numbers are allowed.

```
<input id="charge-hours" type="text" class="charge-position-hours-edit" placeholder="0" ng-model="charge.hours">
```

How to control the setting of ng-model.

I would like write a precondition before the value set in the scope. Something like

```
$scope.precondition = function (value) {
        if (!isNan(value)) {
          $scope.value=value;
        }else{
          //do nothing
        }
      }
```

Is this possible in javascript/angularjs? In jave there would be setter for that.

**EDIT**

My Question was not clear enough.

I really want only positive numbers are typable in the input field, and only positive numbers should be bound to the ng model of angularjs.

Is there a way to save the oldValue if I use ng change? Then I may write something like

```
if (condition===true) //ok 
else $scope.value=oldValue;
```

Comment: Just look at the ["custom validation" part of the angularjs form documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#custom-validation)

Answer (score 0):

if your problem is to make sure the value is an integer and positive you can use HTML5 to validate this.

Check this link [number](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bnumber%5D).

To validate the number you can use the [ng-change](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) directive to control it, if you want more control use [ng-keyup](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeyup).

Also consider looking at "[custom validation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#custom-validation)" part of the angularjs form documentation – just like Patrick Ferreira sugested.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<input id="charge-hours" type="text" class="charge-position-hours-edit" placeholder="0" ng-model="charge.hours" ng-change="precondition()">
```

[source](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange)

Comment: [You can't think like in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background) and listen for user actions ...

AngularJS provides lots of tools for [that kind of things](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#custom-validation)